# Worklight user-agent

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

I've been showing a page on the console (Android environment), and testing if this external page (an html page of mine) has been opened using a mobile device or a desktop by checking the user-agent using this piece of code:

navigator.userAgent.match(/Android/i)

If I run this piece of code on the real device it shows it's an Android device, if I launch the Worklight Console it shows it's a desktop device. How can I change the user-agent in order to let Console think it's an Android device? I've installed the Chrome extension but I didn't understand how to use it.

Comment: What "Chrome extension"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds to me like you want to debug your Android environment (which is meant for mobile devices) while using the Chrome desktop browser?

Try the following and see if this is what you want:

1. Preview the web resources

   - If all your web resources are in the common\css or common\js folder, open Worklight Console and click on "preview web resources"
   - If the web resources are coming from both the common\ and android\ folders, you can use this URL structure: `http://replace-with-host-or-ip-address:10080/replace-with-project-name/apps/services/preview/replace-with-app-name/android/1.0`,
2. Open the Chrome DevTools and click on the device icon:

   [image]
3. Then, from the UI that will open up you can select from the Devices dropdown to adjust the viewport to that of the chosen Android device.

   [image]